# Is it possible to kick users out of a stand alone Access database that is housed in a shared folder?

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, monitoring

I built an Access DB and placed it in a shared folder where users are to copy and paste directly to their desktops.  There are some that are accessing the database directly from the folder; hence locking the database up for any updates to be made.

There are no log in or user credentials used when accessing the database so I can't place any kind of audit trail on it to determine the users that continue to open the database directly from the folder.

Is it possible to close the database; knocking out these individuals that continue to lock it up?  Or is it possible to place some sort of an audit trail in the database to capture user data that would identify the individual; i.e. computer address, computer name, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I originally had it set up that way, but having the tables linked was causing problems so I made it a stand alone database. Another issue is we can't get each user to copy the database to their desktops. I'm not sure how to solve for individuals failing to copy to the database to their desktops. –

Answer (score 1):

You should leave that setup and arrange for each user to always have *their own copy* of the frontend - having tables linked from one backend, if they need that.

A script and a shortcut is used for that. It is described in detail in my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

*(if you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article)*